# htaccess to allow ip addresses but from a generated list

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have a friend who is a little stuck so im trying to help him but over the years of developing and working with apache ive not had to do this so seeing if it is possible so...

i want to do something like this

```
order deny,allow
allow from 79.133.0.0
allow from 82.199.160.0
allow from 91.187.96.0
allow from 194.126.212.0
deny from all
```

however i need to get the list of the allowed ip addresses from another file, example allowed.txt which contains just ip data like

```
79.133.0.0
82.199.160.0
91.187.96.0
194.126.212.0
```

We cannot add "allow from" to that external file as its used by other system services so ideally would like to (if possible) get the files contents and loops through the ip addresses in that file but adding "allow from" before the ip.

As i said, never done anything like this before and dont know of a method that will do this but asking just in case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solved with a trivial script, such as the following

```
#! /bin/sh
echo order deny,allow
sed -e 's|^|allow from |'
echo deny from all
```

executed as

```
name-of-script < external-file > .htaccess
```

The best way to trigger this script would depend on what you were trying to achieve. A cron job would do the job.

Comment: what would be the total code to place into htaccess file? to grab that external list of ip address though? or that part "executed as" is a commend line to run in cron?

Comment: so the bin/sh part into htaccess and the for example setup a cron to fire the command "allowed-ips /path/to/file/iplist.text .htaccess" ? sorry little confused how the above all fits together?

Comment: No the bin/sh part would go in a separate script file. The second part is a command to put in your crontab, substitute name-of-script with the actual filename of the script file you saved my script into.

Comment: ok cool, how does  that cronjob execute the script file to generate the new htaccess from the list of ips? sorry little lost.

Comment: e.g. add this line `@hourly name-of-script < external-file > .htaccess` to your crontab. I don't know what more you want to know, I've told you everything you need to know.

Comment: would you mind letting me know what command to run in a cronjob to execute that script file to then generate the htaccess file with that list of ips inside the htaccess file so the script file is called for example ip-list.sh and i run a cron to execute the ip-list.sh file, get the ip list from /path/to/file.txt and then generate the .htaccess to another location.

Comment: ahh one sec, name-of-script is the name of the script sorry, understand now let me try it - my bad, long day and late night :)

Comment: im getting

Output from command /var/www/script.sh /var/www/htaccess.txt /var/www/html/.htaccess ..

order deny,allow
deny from all

does not seem to be getting the list of ips from the text file and writing to the .htaccess file

Comment: Yes I can see you've missed out the < and the >

Comment: maybe i got it wrong with the < and > but i get this now:

Output from command /var/www/script.sh </var/www/htaccess.txt> /var/www/html/.htaccess ..

No output generated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42159/discussion-between-robin-green-and-james-brandon)